# TVirtualStringTree & toUseExplorerTheme - change color selected item and mouse hover

Tags: delphi, tvirtualstringtree

I'm use TVirtualStringTree+toUseExplorerTheme+toThemeAware for beautiful display. But i need change color of selected item and hover item.
How can this be done?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... If you tell TVT to use the OS theme, then the colors are defined by the OS. What does your TVT look like, and what would you like it to look like? Add a image snip (no fullscreen though) just enough to show what you mean.

Comment: Nothing easy. You will need to override `PrepareCell` method and color blend the theme drawn selection rectangles.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone!
Solved the problem as follows:

SelectionBlendFactor := 0
toUseExplorerTheme+toThemeAware := False

```
procedure MyForm.vtLogBeforeItemErase(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  TargetCanvas: TCanvas; Node: PVirtualNode; ItemRect: TRect;
  var ItemColor: TColor; var EraseAction: TItemEraseAction);

begin
  inherited;
  if not Assigned(Node) then
    Exit;

  EraseAction := eaColor;

  if not Odd(Node.Index) then
    ItemColor := $00FAF7F5
  else
    ItemColor := vtLog.Color;

  if vsSelected in Node.States then begin
    if vtLog.Focused then
      ItemColor := $00D6B693//$E1B959
    else
      ItemColor := $00E9E1D8;
  end
  else
    if vtLog.Focused and Assigned(vtLog.HotNode) and (vtLog.HotNode.Index = Node.Index)  then begin
      ItemColor := $00FBECDC;
    end;
end;
```

And very beautiful all drawing and working.

Comment: The line "SelectionBlendFactor := 0 toUseExplorerTheme+toThemeAware := False" in your answer makes no sense whatever.

Comment: Sorry. addition need toUseBlendSelection := True, else selected item separate by columns.